# How to loop through the pandas dataframe columns using for loop to count the value based on the list given

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to loop through a pandas dataframe's columns using a for loop to count the value based on the list given.

```
My_list =[ 'apple', 'orange', 'grapes' ]
```

I can do it with `value_count()` functions as given below to calculate frequency

```
df['Fruits']. value_count()
```

but I want to calculate using the for loop to iterate over dataframe to get count and average of the list given.

```
My_list =[ 'apple', 'orange', 'grapes' ] 

Df:   
    Fruits  value
    apple      10
    apple      20 
    orange      2
    grapes      5 
    grapes     10 
    grapes      3
```

My output should be like this.

```
Fruits    count    average
apple      2         15 
orange     1          2 
grapes     3          6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- `groupby` and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and `mean`
- rename columns names by `dictionary`
- convert index to column by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

```
My_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes'] 
df1 = (df.query("Fruits in @My_list")
         .groupby('Fruits', sort=False)['value']
         .agg(['size','mean'])
         .rename(columns={'mean':'average', 'size':'count'})
         .reset_index())
```

---

```
df1 = (df[df['Fruits'].isin(My_list)]
        .groupby('Fruits', sort=False)['value']
        .agg(['size','mean'])
        .rename(columns={'mean':'average', 'size':'count'})
        .reset_index())

print (df1)
   Fruits  count  average
0   apple      2       15
1  orange      1        2
2  grapes      3        6
```

If want use loop, it should be slowier:

```
L = []
for x in My_list:
    s = df.loc[df['Fruits'] == x, 'value']
    #print (s)
    L.append({'Fruits': x, 'average':s.mean(), 'count':len(s)})

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Fruits','count','average'])
print (df)
   Fruits  count  average
0   apple      2     15.0
1  orange      1      2.0
2  grapes      3      6.0
```

Comment: I add also loop solution, but faster/ better is use `groupby` + `agg` solution.

Comment: Great. Thanks for listing the different options